# What's the difference between using 'flutter run' and hitting the play button at the top right in Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Title pretty much says it all. What's the difference between using `flutter run` in the Terminal tab in Android Studio versus using the green play button at the top right in Android Studio?

Comment: they are the same - but with `flutter run` you have more options in the menu

Answer (score 0):

I think they pretty much doing the same job. Except for you have to type flutter run in the terminal if you want to run or test your app whereas the play button that is located on top of the screen makes your life much easier and convenience, because you don't have to manually type it !!!